# Does a bijection and a homomorphism imply isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So assume we have two groups A and B. let $\phi_1:A\rightarrow B$ be a bijection, and $\phi_2:A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism where $\phi_1 \neq \phi_2$. Does that imply that some isomorphism exists? It seems to me that an isomorphism should exist in this case since both sets have the same cardinality and have similar algebraic properites, however I couldn't find a proof for it nor a counterexample.

Comment: Ah yes, it is a rather silly question.   Haven't had enough coffee yet. :)

Comment: Notice that the question whether a bijective morphism is an isomorphism is nowhere meaningless. This is a question you have to ask in each category. And in the most categories, the answer will be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not true. The existence of a homomorphism shows nothing, since there is always the trivial homomorphism. For instance there is bijection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$, and also a homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ (one for any rational number...), but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: That's the first example I thought about, but I think that with finite groups it's easier to see. Anyway, as a remark, I would like to add that you can see that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic by noticing that every quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ by a normal subgroup gives a finite group, while the same is not true for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to state why $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ are not isomorphic. There are million of ways to see this...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit rusty on my group theory. I'm curious, could you give a few other ways to see it?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic (not even finitely generated) or every homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ is zero,

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, this will not work. As a counterexample, consider $A,B$ two different finite groups with the same number of elements (e.g. $A=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}_4$), choose any bijection $\phi_1$ and take the trivial homomorphism $\phi_2(a) = 1_B$.